# How To Use Symmetric Key To Encrypt Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

How To Use Symmetric Key  To Encrypt Connection String in Web.config file And What the Code for doing that (with libraries)

Answer (score 2):

use System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvide
Encrype your connection string with simple application. and then add it to your main application. this will use machine key. it will work only with one server, where you have created thsi encryped connection string.
[Protecting Connection Strings and Other Configuration Information](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs)